# VBA 2007 - easy variables task - copying & range

Tags: vba, excel

apologies for disturbing your minds, but I have qq:

Task:
There is a column with one word I need to find ("Kermit"). Then select the cells from "Kermit" down till the one before last . Than change the color and that is it.

Problem:
I wanted to use first variable for the cell with the word Kermit, second one for my eventual, final selection. 
I am really confused with VBA & Variables..
Any idea? Thanks from advance!

```
Sub Muppets()
    Dim Kermit As Range 
    Set Kermit = Cells.Find("Kermit")

    Dim ooo As Range

    Set ooo = Range((Kermit), Range("Kermit").End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0)).Select

    ooo.Interior.Color = rgbLightBlue
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the purpose of your `Offset()` code?  What are you actually trying to select/highlight?

Comment: Let me throw out some possible clarification and please correct me if I am wrong:  You have data and COLUMN HEADERS.  One of those COLUMN HEADERS is "Kermit".  You need to find that header, select the ENTIRE COLUMN (except the last cell in the column), and highlight that all light blue?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want. Will find 'Kermit' within specified worksheet (Kermit), then set only that column from that point to next-to-last row to your color.

```
    Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim LastRow     As Long
    Dim LastCol     As Long
    Dim rng1        As Range
    Dim rng2        As Range
    Dim rng3        As Range

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kermit")
        LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        LastCol = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).column
        Set rng1 = .Cells.Find("Kermit", [A1], xlFormulas, xlPart, , , False)
        If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
            Set rng2 = Rows(LastRow)        'Range(LastRow, rng1.column)
            .Range(Cells(rng1.Row, rng1.column), Cells(LastRow - 1, rng1.column)).Select
        End If
    End With
    Selection.Interior.Color = rgbLightBlue

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

I find in these situations to break it down.  If you can use a 'debug.print' that can help when you are starting out.

The range() function in VBA takes a start and end address.  You have the first one:

Kermit.address

When I looked at the second address, I found it was *before* the cell you had.  Your offset should be positive -  this gets the range on my test sheet:

range(Kermit.address, kermit.offset(1,0).End(xlDown).Address).Address

The function would be like so (you can also use the RGB function):

```
Sub Muppets()
    Dim Kermit As Range
    Set Kermit = Cells.Find("Kermit")

    Dim ooo As Range

    Set ooo = Range(Kermit.Address, Kermit.Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown).Address)

    ooo.Interior.Color = vbBlue ' RGB(0, 0, 255)

End Sub
```